# I installed php module but It is not loaded

Tags: php, gnupg, php-extension

I installed [this](https://github.com/php-gnupg/php-gnupg).

I modified a line in php.ini `extension=gnupg`

`php -m | grep gnupg` shows `gnupg`

And then I made test.php

```
<?php
    phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
?>
```

But It doesn't display gnupg module.

I don't know why now..

Comment: Have you tried a restart of your webserver service (e.g. apache)?

Comment: @Sam020 yes, Can it be related to permission??

Comment: @Sam020 I logged in to server as normal user not root

Comment: I think you would get errors when installing the module and restarting the webserver, if permissions were the issue. But never hurt to check the webserver, system and PHP logs (if you have access to them).